# writing output from void into a .txt file

Tags: java

I try to make a password generator that takes input from the user. When the user key in the details. The system will take the input & generate a password.

```
public void genPass(){
    String name = EnterStudentNameField.getText();
    String nric = EnterNRICField.getText();

    try{
        name = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        nric = nric.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

        String password = name.substring(0,4).toLowerCase() + "@" + nric.substring(nric.length()-3);
        System.out.println(password);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Input Error" +e);
    }
    }
```

I want the output to be able to write into a .txt file along with the details keyed in.

```
    public void saveInfoToTextFile(){    

        Path file = Paths.get("default_password.txt");
        OutputStream output=null;
        try{
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(
                    file,APPEND, CREATE));
            output.write((EnterStudentNameField.getText()+"#").getBytes());
            output.write((EnterNRICField.getText()+ "#").getBytes());
            output.write((genPass()+ "#").getBytes()); //void method cannot be used
            output.write(("\n").getBytes());
            //output.write("End of file...".getBytes());
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Message "+ e);
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that it said that I can't pass a void method in the output.write.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getPass() should return a String so the method should be of type String. On an unrelated note, your try-catch is likely catching an IndexOutOfBoundsException/NullPointerException that would indicate there is a problem with your logic. It's almost never a good idea to fail silently.

```java
public String genPass(){
    String name = EnterStudentNameField.getText();

    String nric = EnterNRICField.getText();

    name = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

    nric = nric.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

    return name.substring(0,4).toLowerCase() + "@" + nric.substring(nric.length()-3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just run your code with little modification, it works,
for example for "John Wilson" it saves to txt file : ##john@son#
I wonder it this is what you wanted?

```
private static void saveInfoToTextFile()
{

    Path file = Paths.get("default_password.txt");
    OutputStream output = null;
    try
    {
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(
                file, APPEND, CREATE));
        output.write((EnterStudentNameField.getText() + "#").getBytes());
        output.write((EnterNRICField.getText() + "#").getBytes());
        output.write((genPass() + "#").getBytes()); //void method cannot be used
        output.write(("\n").getBytes());
        //output.write("End of file...".getBytes());
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Message " + e);
    }
}

private static String genPass()
{
    String name = EnterStudentNameField.getText();
    String nric = EnterNRICField.getText();

    //String name = "John";
    //String nric = "Wilson";

    String password = null;
    try
    {
        name = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        nric = nric.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        password = name.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase() + "@" + nric.substring(nric.length() - 3);
        System.out.println(password);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Input Error" + e);
    }
    return password;
}
```